# VM Ware Windows XP Mode failed to import

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware

Im having trouble when importing Windows XP Mode in VM Ware. When I click "Import Windows XP Mode VM" then click Import, it says "Failed to import Windows XP Mode" with no following explanation. My Windows XP Mode has been installed correctly and I've also tried to reinstall both the vmware and windows xp mode but nothing changes. 
PS : Im running on 64 bit Win7 Ultimate

Answer (score 3):

VMWare discontinued VHD support in version 6.0

https://www.vmware.com/support/converter/doc/conv_sa_60_rel_notes.html

> Third-party backup images and virtual machines - to be discontinued
>
> ```
> The Microsoft VHD format
> ```

So you need to download 5.5 instead

https://download2.vmware.com/software/vi/VMware-converter-en-5.5.3-2183569.exe

Comment: That link is dead; go to https://my.vmware.com/en/group/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter then expand "Version History" at bottom to find 5.5.3 link

Comment: I couldn't find "Version History", I found a [link in the forums to 5.5.3.](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/get-download?downloadGroup=CONV553_GA)